# Why is there an access violation on connecting to MongoDB from C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb, access-violation, mongo-cxx-driver

When I try to run this little piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri{}};
    mongocxx::database db = client["xyz"];
    std::cout << "Connected to xyz." << std::endl;
}
```

I always get this warning

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF7815F1FD (libmongoc-1.0.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000020.
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
mongocxx::instance instance{};
```

as the first line of code in the main function.